# JIRA REST API get all users

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to **get all users** from **JIRA REST API**. I need to save all users to my Database from my own java client.  **Is it possible to do that ?**

If so how we going to do that?

Comment: There's a request on Atlassian.com to implement this feature: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-29069.

Comment: You can use `Get-JiraUser -Username '%' -IncludeInactive -Credential $cred` from the PSJira library: https://github.com/replicaJunction/PSJira. / http://stackoverflow.com/a/42086207/361842.

Comment: Shockingly bad API

Answer (score 12):

At present time:

**for Jira Cloud:**

to get all (active + inactive) users:

```
GET /rest/api/2/users/search?query
```

to get all active users:

```
GET /rest/api/2/user/search?query
```

**for Jira Server:**

to get all (active + inactive) users:

```
GET /rest/api/2/user/search?username=.&includeInactive=true
```

to get all active users:

```
GET /rest/api/2/user/search?username=.
```

Comment: By default Jira returns only 50 items. To get more, `maxResults` can be used. For example `GET /rest/api/2/user/search?username=.&maxResults=1000`.

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be an undocumented way:

Use the "Find user" api

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/user-findUsers

For the username query use %

EG:
/rest/api/2/user/search?username=%

Comment: This does not work for me, using JIRA v6.4.3; perhaps it does in 7.0+?  Querying `.../rest/api/2/user/search?username=e`, for example, returns several results, but `.../rest/api/2/user/search?username=%` or `...=%25` returns nothing.

Comment: Try `/user/search` with param `username` = `.` instead.
Eg.  `/rest/api/2/user/search?username=.&includeActive=true&includeInactive=false` to get all active users.

Comment: But how to get inactive users? Parameter includeInactive is deprecated in APi v3.

Comment: This will fail if there are more than 1000 results. Well, it won't "fail", but you'll never get more than 1000, even with the "startAt" param...

Answer (score 6):

You can get all users that are assignable to a specific project. If everyone is assignable you will get all users.

```
/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?project=PROJECT
```

Curl:

```
curl -D -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?project=PROJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get all of the users in your JIRA instance is to use the Crowd API's [`/rest/usermanagement/1/search`](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/3.3.0/REST/?_ga=2.127108104.420787522.1539346027-1959143659.1535621273#usermanagement/1/search-search) endpoint:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://jira.url/rest/usermanagement/1/search?entity-type=user&start-index=0&max-results=1000&expand=user' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' -u username:password
```

Do note that you'll need to create a new [JIRA User Server entry](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/allowing-connections-to-jira-for-user-management-861253193.html?_ga=2.190112174.406123383.1540817096-1953942423.1531498219) to create Crowd credentials (the `username:password` parameter above) for your application to use in its REST API calls:

- Go to User Management.
- Select JIRA User Server.
- Add an application.
- Enter the application name and password that the application will use when accessing your JIRA server application.
- Enter the IP address, addresses, or IP CIDR block of the application, and click Save.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
https://company_name.altassian.net/rest/api/3/users/search?
```

It will return something like this:

```
[
{
    "accountId": "id",
    "accountType": "app",
    "avatarUrls": {},
    "displayName": "Slack",
    "active": true
},
{
    "self": "profile_link of ther user",
    "accountId": "id",
    "accountType": "atlassian",
    "avatarUrls": {},
    "displayName": "**Real user**",
    "active": true,
    "locale": "en_US"
}
]
```

Before saving to DB you'll have to check the `accountType`:

```
if (accountType == 'altassian') {
      then do push; // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread but if anyone is searching for this now, this works for me at the moment:

```
GET /rest/api/latest/user/search?query=+&maxResults=1000
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: I get 400 error "The username query parameter was not provided" as is.  If I add &username=someuser it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to get all users in Jira Rest API. You might have to use Search function(Which requires passing in atleast one letter to search) or Groups functions, if you have users readily grouped in Jira application.

Go through their documentation for better reference.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e808

You can use simple JDBC scripts to some advanced ones for writing users list to database, through your java client.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

I also suffered with this problem for a long time. I had a task search by project completed tasks by user. Answer:
https://developer.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql = project = yourProject + AND + status = done + AND + assignee= yourUser

Comment: Page not found error when clicking on the link that you have provided in your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30210691)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question - You can't formulate a JQL query that will return a list of users without writing a [custom function](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/role-members-jql-function-tutorial/).